# Theming Views problem to print view fields

Tags: views, theming

I was trying to edit my view theme with php in the file
**views-view-field--homepage-banner--block--field-site-image.tpl.php**
and try to print view fields, but values come's empty. any ideas?

Code example:

```
<?php
$link=$fields['field_site_image_link']->content;
$src=$fields['field_site_image']->content;
$link2 = '/' . strip_tags($fields['field_site_image_link']->content);
print $src;
print $link2;
?>
<a href="<?php echo $fields['field_site_image_link']->content; ?>"><?php echo $fields['field_site_image']->content; ?></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

1- clear cache
2- take the views-view-field.tpl.php source as a starting point for doing what you need also have a look at documentation at the top of the file